# "Errors in android studio, Need solution for 'Please update emulator to support Vulkan feature' and 'Running multiple emulators with the same AVD'

Tags: flutter, android-emulator, google-pixel

I tried running my flutter code written in android studio with an emulator i already installed. However, I have two emulator devices installed. When i select the preffered emulator and it launches, It gives this error and doesn't actually run on the selected device. here is the error "
"Encountering errors while running Flutter code in Android Studio with Google Pixel emulator: Need solution for 'Please update emulator to support Vulkan feature' and 'Running multiple emulators with the same AVD'"

I tried to select an emulator but it wasn't selected. I expected that the code will appear on the emulator but it didn't however, the emulator launched but isn't running the code.